# PHP Script Not erroring and not running

Tags: php, sql

My code is this:

```
<?php
echo "Test1";
$con=mysqli_connect("Removed");

$Amount=$_GET["Amount"];
$GetType=$_GET["Type"];
var_dump($GetType);
var_dump($Amount);
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM EventRecord WHERE EventType='$GetType' ORDER BY EventId DESC";
$sql_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)
     or exit(mysqli_error($con));
while($sql_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)){
   echo $sql_row['EventId'].'<br>';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

For some reason, when I go to http://www.example.com/MyPhp.php?Type=Join&Amount=10, all that is outputted is "Test1string(4) string(2)". 
Note: I am aware of SQL Injection vulnerabilities, however they do not affect me specifically with this code. All table structure is correct.

Additionally, how would I make it echo the top rows, as determined by how large the EventId is, but echo only the top 2, or top 3, or top 7, or top any other number, depending on what $Amount is?

Comment: maybe you should describe the table structure and provide some formatted output for us to answer this. "Test1string(4) string(2)" this looks like you're doing the an echo first "Test1" and then you're getting the 2 vardumps string(4) & string(2). If you want to limit your result you can use mysql's LIMIT n   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: As I said, there is no output.

Comment: For that you can give order by your column name and can give the limit 0,7

Comment: What output would you expect if no records were returned?

Comment: "No records were returned" why do you think that would happen?

Comment: No records would be returned if there were no records on the database with an `EventType` matching the value of `$GetType`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$sql_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)
     or exit(mysqli_error($con));
```

With

```
if(!($sql_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))) {
    exit(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

See :
[PHP: mysqli::$error - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)
and [PHP: mysqli::query - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Missing one closing parenthesis at if statement there.

Comment: Are you sure you have errors enabled in PHP's configuration file ? Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the LIMIT to display the first $Amount results from the database?

```
SELECT * FROM EventRecord WHERE EventType='$GetType' ORDER BY EventId DESC LIMIT 0, $Amount
```

Please correct me if I your question.

Comment: I think that would be right, however I believe $Amount is a string, does that matter?

Comment: Should be fine. Or you can cast it to integer first.

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''3'' at line 1" (I was using 3 for the amount)

Comment: Please remove the quote for $Amount.

Comment: Well, that's not erroring now... "Test1string(4) "Join" string(1) "3"" is the output, so it doesn't seem to be running

Comment: Could you please try to echo something before the while loop? I'm afraid that the program exited before reaching the while loop. if that is not possible, then probably the table doesn't have any result returned when EventType="Join".

You can aslo use `mysqli_num_rows` to find out number of rows in the result first before the loop.